# Use generic struct with protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

It seems that Swift generics work fine, as long as I don't try to combine them in any practical way. I'm using Swift 4.1, and I would like to create a generic array containing only weak references. I can define this as `WeakList<T>`. So far so well. But: I would like to use a protocol for `T`. Swift says nope..

```swift
import Foundation

protocol Observer: class {
    func stateChanged(sender: SomeClass, newState: Int)
}

struct WeakList<T> where T: AnyObject {
    struct Ptr {
        weak var p: T?
    }
    private var storage: [Ptr] = []
    var aliveObjects: [T] {
        var result: [T] = []
        for ptr in storage {
            if let p = ptr.p {
                result.append(p)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    mutating func add(_ obj: T) {
        storage.append(Ptr(p: obj))
    }
    // Let's ignore for a moment that this implementation leaks memory badly.
}

class SomeClass {
    var someVar: WeakList<Observer> = WeakList<Observer>()
    // Error: WeakList requires that 'Observer' be a class type

    var thisIsOk: WeakList<NSObject> = WeakList<NSObject>()
}
```

(this is not my original code but a minimal verifyable example that contains enough details so that no one can say "just remove the AnyObject constraint from the structure")

I guess what I'm trying to do is just not possible. Or is it? It's just frustrating how 4 out of 5 times when I try to do something with Swift generics, I later learn that what I am trying to do is just not possible. (I can implement the same thing in Objective-C easily, by the way.)

- I tried changing the `class` constraint to an `AnyObject` constraint => doesn't work either.
- I tried to change the `AnyObject` constraint to a `class` constraint => doesn't even compile.
- And changing it to `protocol Observer where Self: NSObject` doesn't change anything. `NSObject` is a class type, `Observer` is an `NSObject`. It should follow that `Observer` is a class type. The "is a" relationship doesn't seem to be transitive here.

Comment: if you add @objc to your protocol definition it would work as well and you could remove the `: class`

Comment: @Serj: Yes, I know. The only problem with that is that I cannot do that. E.g. I need to pass a struct to one method. At another point I passed an (Int, Int): okay, I could fix that and pass two Ints instead. There is no clean solution in my case. I solved it by making the WeakList fileprivate and by making it non-generic. The underlying problem here is that a class protocol does not conform to AnyObject, or more generally that protocols do not conform to themselves; with (AT)objc protocols being the only exception. (Only one AT-character is allowed in a comment on SO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current implementation you cannot inherit the protocol from `AnyObject`. What you can do is to create a Type Eraser for your protocol and use that instead. Now your type eraser can be inherited from `AnyObject`.

Something like this:

```
protocol Observer {
    func stateChanged(sender: SomeClass, newState: Int)
}

class AnyObserver: NSObject, Observer {
    private let observer: Observer

    init(observer: Observer) {
        self.observer = observer
    }

    func stateChanged(sender: SomeClass, newState: Int) {
        observer.stateChanged(sender: sender, newState: newState)
    }
}

struct WeakList<T> where T: AnyObject {
    struct Ptr {
        weak var p: T?
    }
    private var storage: [Ptr] = []
    var aliveObjects: [T] {
        var result: [T] = []
        for ptr in storage {
            if let p = ptr.p {
                result.append(p)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    mutating func add(_ obj: T) {
        storage.append(Ptr(p: obj))
    }
    // Let's ignore for a moment that this implementation leaks memory badly.
}

class SomeClass {
    var someVar: WeakList<AnyObserver> = WeakList<AnyObserver>()

    var thisIsOk: WeakList<NSObject> = WeakList<NSObject>()
}
```